# How to make UniqueTogetherValidator run after validate method in drf?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have both validate and get_unique_together_validators method in my serializer that is used to validate in ViewSet create method, something like this:

```
class CarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   ...
    def validate(self, data):
        validated_data = super().validate(data)
        validated_data['car_maker'] = validated_data['car'].maker
        return validated_data

    def get_unique_together_validators(self):
        return [
            serializers.UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Cars.objects.all(),
                fields=('year', 'car_maker'),
            )
        ]
```

So field 'car_maker' is not required in post body, and is created in the validate method if not passed. The problem is that get_unique_together_validators runs before validate method. How can it be changed? I tried to call get_unique_together_validators within validate method, to call validate within get_unique_together_validators. Tried to ask ChatGPT, he advised to override run_validators method, but every step encounters new errors, and the code grows every time. I don't understand why such logic is in drf, cause it seems right to run unique validator method in create request after common validate method, doesn't it?